# JWT token Error preventing backend api connection Node/Express MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt

I am creating a blogging application using Node, Express and Next.js.  I have successfully deployed the frontend portion of the application however I am running into an error when trying to connect to the backend server:

> Error: secret should be set

[image]

Here is a link to my Github with all the code https://github.com/DragonKnightLeo/Blog-API

This is my first fullstack application so I am pretty junior at how all this works.

Comment: You get this error on your auth.js file line 72, which means that your process.env jwt token is not set, most likely its null..

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the code and tried to see if I can run your code in my local.
Also, saw the error that is coming when you run the code in your logs above. Seems like you do not have a .env file or JWT_SECRET mentioned in your env file.

[image]

Try adding env file and use dotenv node module to bootstrap it along the server run.

Comment: I have added the .env file and have gotten past the previous error. Now I am getting a different error (Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000)

Comment: Check the running instances. There might be another instance with 8000 port number

Comment: I believe there is. How do I stop other ports running?

Comment: Check for netstat -a -b in windows or netstat -plnt for linux

Comment: Once you get the Process ID (PID) of the application running on port 8000. You can kill it with "Kill PID"

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Comment: Great. Glad to help

Comment: And btw, please do not check in .env file in github. Also its public

Comment: how would the server get the JWT secret if the .env file is not in github?

Comment: You have to manually add the env file to the server or write a script such as jenkins or yuml file for sonarkube for pullling the .env file from some secure location lets say personal AWS.